# Open new file when created/placed/saved/stored in directory/folder with batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Hello people on Stack Overflow!

I've searched a lot on the internet, but I didn't get anything relevant.

I am writing a script that opens a file directly once placed in directory. So let's say I have the directory:

```
F:\Files
```

Now I download a file to that folder. The following will be created:

```
F:\Files\download.zip    REM This is the actual file, but 0 KB
F:\Files\download.part   REM This is the content of the *.zip, until it is fully downloaded.
```

So which script could I use to open download.zip when its size equals larger than 1 byte?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `%1` is the file name passed to the script as an argument, you could do something like this:

```
IF %~z1 GTR 0 (
  commands to process the file
)
```

`%~z1` evaluates to the size of the file specified in `%1`. `GTR` means *greater than*, so the condition checks if the size is greater than 0, and if that is true, the *`commands to process the file`* are executed.

Comment: I presumed you already had that part done, and I can see now that it was a bit premature of me to do so. But otherwise I must say that your question is somewhat vague as to what you've already got at this moment. In fact, from some angle, one could derive from your question that presently you've got nothing at all. Either way, you really should ask one thing at a time. That is less discouraging to people and will grant you more chances to get the best answer to every question.

Answer (score 0):

This bach file should do what you want (not sure if it will work on all versions of Windows).

It is using [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m)'s script, but adds the functionality you requested.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET dirname=F:\Files

:Begin
CLS
ECHO %TIME%
FOR /R "%dirname%\" %%a IN (*.zip) DO CALL :process1 %%a
ping.exe localhost -n 11 >nul
GOTO Begin

:process1
IF %~z1 GTR 0 "%1"
GOTO :EOF
```

The `ping.exe localhost -n 11 >nul` is just a delay, so that you can leave the batch file running and it will loop about every 10 seconds as defined with `-n 11` which results in 11 pings of local host in intervals of 1 second with first one successful already after some microseconds.

I've added the command line `ECHO %TIME%` so that it can be seen it is still working as this time value updates every loop iteration.

There is a drawback to this batch solution. If the ZIP file is still in the directory when the next loop run occurs, it opens the ZIP file once again.